# How to get json object beginning with "@" in Golang

Tags: json, go

How to get json object beginning with "@" like:

```
{ 
 ...   
 "@meta": {
        "serverTimeMs": 114,
        "requestId": "F45FDGH35HF7"
      }
 ...
}
```

Comment: An object can't start with a `@` - that is a key. Is that the exact json you're trying to decode (which would be invalid), or is that a piece of a larger object?

Comment: Yes! It's a part from a big object.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're doing, because there's nothing special in the JSON you posted and it can be unmarshaled without problems.

Comment: Then tag the field `@meta` just like you would for `serverTimeMs` or `requestId` If you're unmarshaling into a map, then it "just works" already.

Comment: It's my example: https://play.golang.org/p/qYDY479nIw

Comment: Thanks! Ok! I understood my mistake! Unexported fields))

Comment: @AndreyK. , Please add a struct which you declared to unmarshal the json obj to your question. In this way it will be useful for others and worthy for up-votes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to unmarshal it into a struct you can use a tag to specify the name of the json key:

```
type data struct {
  Meta map[string]interface{} `json:"@meta"`
}
```

example code: https://play.golang.org/p/ts6QJac8iH

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I understood my mistake! Unexported fields in my example))

Answer (score 2):

`encoding/json` package uses tags to describe marshaling/unmarshaling json object. So you should define a tag describing json obj on a struct to unmarshal it. And `reflect` package uses tags with [`StructTag`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) type

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

[Tag usage example](https://play.golang.org/p/aza8-o0ZcW):

```
type TargetsResult struct {
    Meta map[string]interface{} `json:"@meta"`
}

func main() {
    var results TargetsResult
    input := `{ "@meta": { "serverTimeMs": 114, "requestId": "F45FDGH35HF7" } }`
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &results); err != nil {
         fmt.Print(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", results)
}
```

Note, `json` uses `reflect` for tags so to be able in `reflect` all the struct fields must be exportable (i.e. start with uppercase letter).